# Address Autocomplete: Manual or Autocomplete

Tags: usability, autocomplete, addresses, ease-of-use

We are currently under going a re-design in a a sign up process for getting your house connected to electricity and natural gas.

The first step asks you to enter your address in a number of fields as shown:

[image: Form "Service address", with fields like "Street name" and "City"]

In an effort to reduce steps and space in the sign up, the suggestion was made to integrate an auto complete feature such as this:

[image: Form "Service address", with an autocomplete field]

Which method of entry is more effective and optimal for the user? and what are the pitfalls of converting to an autocomplete widget over manual entry? Initial usability testing has shown that from a group of 100 users, 60 users preferred autocomplete, the other 40% preferred manual entry.

Comment: What does the phrase '60% over 40%' mean?

Comment: 60% of users preferred autocomplete, as opose to 40% who preferred the manual input, good catch - will update the question.

Answer (score 4):

You've answered your first question (*Which method of entry is more effective...*):

> Initial usability testing has shown that from a group of 100 users, 60 users preferred autocomplete...

A couple of pitfalls would be

- A user's address might not be in the auto complete list.  eg A new housing development. 
  An article about the [invalid autocomplete addresses](https://smartystreets.com/archive/why-would-autocomplete-suggest-an-invalid-address)
- The accessiblity of the auto-complete widget should be assessed. [WebAIM on Widgets](http://webaim.org/techniques/aria/#widget)